# How do I keep track of how an instance attribute's value is changed across multiple methods? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am new to Python and I am learning object oriented programming. However, I have one question which I cannot find the answer to anywhere

Assume that I have the example below:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x1 = 10
        self.y1 = 100

    def thing1(self, x, y):
        x += 5
        y += 10
        print(x, y)

    def thing2(self, x, y):
        x += 10
        print(x)

node = Node()

def main():
    node.thing1(node.x1, node.y1)
    node.thing2(node.x1, node.y1)

main()
```

The output I get when I run this code is the following:

```
15 110
20
```

But the output I wanted to get was:

```
15 110
25
```

For some reason python does not track how the value of the instance variable is changed across multiple methods

I know that I can just change the value to the instance attribute directly in the method and that will work, but I am curious to the solution to this problem in the example I provided above.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me with this issue because it has been puzzling me for quite some time.

Comment: You're not changing any instance variables in these methods. `x` and `y` are just local variables.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` always going to be `self.x1` and `self.y1`(,that is variables of an instance), or do you want the changes to be tracked for any variable?

Comment: That is you want to pass `x` and `y` by reference. This is different depending on what `x` and `y` is. In your case if you want just `self.x1` and `self.y1` what @zvone pointed out is the solution. if you want `x` and `y` to be anything you'll have to resort to other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this function:

```
def thing1(self, x, y):
    x += 5
    y += 10
    print(x, y)
```

1. You seem to actually want to modify the object's attributes `self.x` and `self.y`, but you are only modifying some temporary local variables `x` an `y`.
2. You are passing `x` and `y` values, although they are not needed.

You have the same problems with the other function as well.

This would be the corrected code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 100

    def thing1(self):
        self.x += 5
        self.y += 10
        print(self.x, self.y)

    def thing2(self):
        self.x += 10
        print(self.x)

def main():
    node = Node()
    node.thing1()
    node.thing2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yes I understand I can do it that way.

Comment: However, I want to see if I can pass x1 and y1 as arguments to the method. So instead of referencing directly to x1, I want to reference to it through a local variable called x which will become x1 when I call that method in the function called main. When I modify the value of x in the method called thing1, I want the value of x1 to be the modified value of x, but I do not want to reference to it directly. Then in the method called thing2 I want the modified value of x1 to be the value of x in the method.

Comment: @TrashDev When you pass `self.x1`, the way you did, you are just passing its value, i.e. `10`. You cannot modify `self.x1` that way. You cannot pass a reference to an integer somewhere to modify the integer, because integers are immutable objects in Python.

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally solved the problem I greatly appreciate your help.